# Ubuntu 12.04 Samba File Server timeout on large file

Tags: samba, timeout, ubuntu-12.04

I am a beginner with servers. I checked the error logs for Samba and it appears that Samba is timing out when I transfer large files. I can successfully add PDFs for instance to my file server. However, I tried to add a large 1.2GB video file and it did not succeed. This is the error in the log:

```
smbd/process.c:244(read_packet_remainder)
read_fd_with_timeout failed for client 0.0.0.0 read error = NT_STATUS_CONNECT$
```

Is there a way I can stop it from timing out? Any pointers would be great.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ubuntu Server - Error adding videos/large files to file server?](http://serverfault.com/questions/443066/ubuntu-server-error-adding-videos-large-files-to-file-server)

Comment: @ErikA The Q got deleted, it's not a dupe anymore...

Comment: @Jacob - that q was deleted by its owner, who also happens to be the owner of this question. Deletion in bad faith, IMHO.

Comment: Guys, if you have something real to say, please post. I actually need help and am getting none while you just bicker about the particulars.

Comment: Do you observe any other errors? Did you check `dmesg`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After weeks I finally found it. There is a line in smb.conf that sets no delay on the connection. It is by default commented out. I merely uncomment the line and voila! This is the line:

```
 socket options = TCP_NODELAY
```

it is by default commented out. If you are having an issue with this, uncomment that line in your smb.conf and restart samba.

Answer (score 1):

Is your client machine running Linux too? [Some](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=126328) people report that this problem is solved by [disabling opportunistic locking](http://blog.dhampir.no/content/cifs-vfs-no-response-for-cmd-n-mid), which you can do by simply running the command:

```
echo 0 > /proc/fs/cifs/OplockEnabled
```

Looking at the second post reveals that the author suggests doing that immediately after loading the `cifs` module; in that case the correct sequence would be, after unmounting your network share:

```
rmmod cifs
modprobe cifs
echo 0 > /proc/fs/cifs/OplockEnabled
```

I wouldn't know whether it makes any difference, though.